# rSpec destroy files after suite finishes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, rspec-rails

In my rSpec tests I test paperclip's ability to upload photos to my system and save them with a given user.

This is great however upon my tests finishing, i have all these extra files on my system. How do i auto delete this upon completion of my test suite.

thanks
mike

Comment: after each you should run Photo.delete_all so he removes the db entry and image

Comment: Know how to delete the folder of uploaded attachments in MInitest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've not used Paperclip, but I assume those files are saved in a somewhat constant place, such as (random example) **tmp/paperclip/photos/**.

If that's the case, within your spec_helper, you can add:

```
config.after(:suite) do # or :each or :all
    Dir["#{Rails.root}/tmp/paperclip/**/*"].each do |file|
        File.delete(file)
    end
end
```

Comment: If you change the last `*` to `*.*` then you avoid trying to delete directories.

Comment: What if you use minitest?

Answer (score 11):

It's simpler to just delete the entire `test` directory.  Plus, *slightly* less overhead and easier to read.

```
# spec_helper.rb

config.after(:suite) do
  FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir["#{Rails.root}/public/system/test"])
end
```

Comment: This assumes that you are using :rails_env in your :path, like so: `path: ':rails_root/public/system/:rails_env/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'`